# Is there any wire with many small wires which i can use for multiple video signal

Tags: video, wire

I have 6-7 cameras at one location. The problem is i don't want to have separate cable for 8 different cameras comming to my room.

I am looking for one big wire in which i can have small 12-14 wires so that i use pairs to carry video signal in one wire only.

Also my camera man was saying that we can use Cat6 cable for carrying 4 video signals with 8 wires. Is there any type of wire avaible with more small wires that cat6

Comment: You need to specify the type of signal that will pass through the wire. Is it digital or analog? What's the format or carrier frequency? Do you also need to provide power? What is the maximum length of wire needed? What is expected in the operating environment: temperature, water, UV exposure, etc.? Your answers to these questions will provide the important parameters in cable selection: bandwidth capacity (a function of signal frequency), attenuation, and mechanical properties. http://blog.solidsignal.com/showthread.php/505-CABLES-101-How-to-choose-the-best-cable-Part-1-types-of-cables

Comment: Is this analog or digital? SDI? HDMI? Is this Standard Definition or High Definition? Is this for low-end video like surveillance? Or for high-end video like broadcast production? Or something in-between. What length do you need? What is your budget? There are many possible solutions to your question, but we have no idea which might be appropriate to you because we don't know the answer to any of those questions above.

Answer (score 6):

[This 3M cable](http://multimedia.3m.com/mws/mediawebserver?6666660Zjcf6lVs6EVs666UdICOrrrrQ-) is available in 7 to 50 twisted pairs. Outer diameter for the 8 pairs is 5.84mm. Available from [Digikey](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/3644B%2F16%20100SF/MB16T-100-ND/1190476), not cheap.

[image]

The ends shown seem to be untwisted, which often happens during stripping of the isolation. If you want to be sure the cable has enough twists (about 1 full twist every 5cm is nice), ask a sample from 3M.

Make sure to check the cable's impedance.